# How to move a function from a class to another class without passing the calling object

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, trie

I have the following implementation for the data structure (Trie) and it is working as expected. I have the main class `Node` and a wrapper class `Trie`. I want to move the function `_insert()` from the `Node` class to `Trie` class to keep `Node` as simple as possible. But I am facing many issues such as `class Trie has no object nodes and no object word.` Is there a way to do it without passing the calling object from the main in ?
Expectations:

```
trie.insert("Hi")
```

All implementation of `insert()` in class Trie

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.word = None
        self.nodes = {}

    def _insert(self, word, string_pos=0):
        current_lettter = word[string_pos]
        if current_lettter not in self.nodes:
            self.nodes[current_lettter] = Node()
        if(string_pos + 1 == len(word)):
            self.nodes[current_lettter].word = word
        else:
            self.nodes[current_lettter]._insert(word, string_pos + 1)

        return True


class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node()

    def insert(self, word):
        self.root._insert(word)

trie = Trie()
trie.insert("Hi")
```

Comment: Rather than having `Trie` create a single instance of a `Node()` inside, would it make more sense for your use-case to use [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) and have it inherit from the `Node` class?

Comment: Thank you so much @G.Anderson. But I prefer to implement it in this way without inheritance. Would you please let me know if there is anyway to move _insert() function to Trie class

Comment: I don;t know what to say except that this code works for me. Can you provide a full error traceback? If I run the above, I can see `trie.root.nodes` `{'H': <__main__.Node at 0x19e89653eb8>}`, and `trie.root.nodes['H'].nodes` gives `{'i': <__main__.Node at 0x19e89653f28>}`, according to the nature of your recursive function

Comment: @G.Anderson it is pretty standard to have a "container" class for nodes. A `Trie` is not a `Node`, it is a *collection of nodes*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I figured this was a structure I am unfamiliar with, but the code runs exactly as written without the error in the question description. That's why I figured my response(s) would be better as comments than answers, seems like maybe an `x-y` problem

Answer (score 0):

class Trie (as implemented) has no object nodes and no object word.

class Trie has only root.nodes and root.word objects.